# Eventlistener for paper-dropdown-menu in Lit-html

Tags: paper-elements, lit-html

I'm in a lit-html project and using some of the material design elements from Google. paper-xxx.

I'm struggling to get an event fired from the `paper-dropdown-menu`. I have implemented it like below:

In render()

```
<paper-dropdown-menu 
    label="Change position"
    id="changePositionDropdown">
    <paper-listbox 
        slot="dropdown-content" 
        class="dropdown-content"                 
        selected="${this.positionForVideoInPlaylist-1}">
    <paper-item value="1">1</paper-item>
    <paper-item value="2">2</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

firstUpdated()

```
const changePositionDropdown = document.getElementById("changePositionDropdown");
    changePositionDropdown.addEventListener('iron-select', (e)=>{
        console.log("Hello there");
    });
```

I'm not entirely sure if `iron-select` would be the correct event to listen to, but seems like it according to this:

> Applications can listen for the `iron-select` and `iron-deselect` events
>   to react when options are selected and deselected
>   Source: [github line: 63](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu/blob/master/paper-dropdown-menu.js)

Would it be correct to use `iron-select` for listening when the selected item changes? And what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is embarassing, forgot about the shadowroot.

This works

```
firstUpdated(){
 const changePositionDropdown = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#changePositionDropdown');

    changePositionDropdown.addEventListener('iron-select', (e)=>{
        console.log("Hello there");
    });
}
```

It's also possible to use the `@event`: [handle-fired-event](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/events#handle-fired-event)

```
<paper-dropdown-menu 
    label="Endre rekkefølge"
    id="changePositionDropdown"
    @iron-select="${(e)=>{console.log("surprise")}}"> <!-- using the @ to handle the vent-->
    <paper-listbox 
        slot="dropdown-content" 
        class="dropdown-content" 
        selected="${this.positionForVideoInPlaylist-1}">
        <paper-item>1</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Comment: Also, I tried paper-dropdown-menu recently with lit-element. In the end I used @selected-changed="${(e) => {this.changedHandler(e)}}"> on the paper-listbox element and using e.detail.value in the handler. See this post also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56067112/paper-dropdown-menu-not-working-in-a-lit-element