# paper-dropdown-menu not working in a lit-element

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, custom-element, lit-element

**Edit**: Turns out, it helps if you import `paper-listbox` before using it in another element. For some reason I thought it was being imported as a dependency on another element I *was* importing, but no.  As soon as I added the explicit import, it began working correctly. Original question follows.

To start, this problem only happens when using `paper-dropdown-menu` (with `paper-listbox` inside) in a `lit-element`. We're using the component in almost the exact same way in multiple `PolymerElement`(s) with no issues.

Basically, I'm seeing two issues with `paper-dropdown-menu`. The first is that it never displays a value of any type, whether the `label` attribute or an actual selected value, nor does its `value` property ever change, even when the `paper-listbox` inside has a set value.  The second problem is that it appears to be impossible to select any value from the dropdown menu - you can click on them, but the list doesn't close, and the selected option name doesn't show up in the menu's text display.

Due to the nature of the issues, it appears as though the problem is that the `paper-dropdown-menu` and the `paper-listbox` inside of it aren't communicating properly... but I'll be damned if I can figure out why.

Here's the markup in question from the element's `render` method:

```html
    <paper-dropdown-menu id="homepageSelect">
        <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" 
            attr-for-selected="item-value" 
            selected="${state.homepage}"
            label="Select a homepage"
            @selected-changed="_homepageChanged">
    
            ${state.homepageOptions.map(o => html`
                <paper-item item-value="${o.value}">${o.name}</paper-item>
            `)}
    
        </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

And the mock data we're using:

```json
    {
        "title": "Boss of you",
        "fullName": "J Jonah Jameson",
        "username": "jjj",
        "client": "Daily Bugle",
        "homepage": "http://sampledomain.com/",
        "homepageOptions": [{
            "name": "FrontPage",
            "value": "http://sampledomain.com/"
        }, {
            "name": "Editorials",
            "value": "http://sampledomain.com/opinion"
        }, {
            "name": "Metro",
            "value": "http://sampledomain.com/metro"
        }],
        "groups": [{
            "name": "Admin",
            "description": "Administers the whole shebang"
        }, {
            "name": "Power users",
            "description": "Like regular users, but powerful"
        }, {
            "name": "Gen pop",
            "description": "Down in the weeds"
        }],
        "changePasswordUrl": "https://change.password.now",
        "email": "test@email.com",
        "phoneWork": "404-555-1234",
        "phoneCell": "404-555-4321",
        "phoneHome": "404-123-5555",
        "address": {
            "address1": "1234 Boulevard St",
            "address2": "Ste 1",
            "city": "Atlanta",
            "state": "GA",
            "zip": "30303",
            "country": "USA",
            "type": "Office"
        }
    }
```

I'd put up a screenshot of how it looks, but just imagine a dropdown with nothing selected, and you've got it. Clicking it actually does display the internal `paper-listbox`, but the list does not close on click, nor does the clicked value ever make it up to the `paper-dropdown-menu` element.

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Theoretically, a `PolymerElement` should be able to run inside of any form of HTML markup - the fact that it's within a `lit-element` shouldn't make a difference, and doesn't for every other component we're using. Nevertheless, this component, using this pattern, works in `PolymerElement` but does not work here, and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It never displays a value of any type, whether the `label` attribute or an actual selected value, nor does its `value` property ever change, even when the `paper-listbox` inside has a set value

Inside of the template you're referencing `state`. If `state` is a property of the  element then you have to reference it with `this.` (unless it's a variable you defined in the part of the `render()` function you didn't paste here). This may be the cause of the missing values.

The missing label is because you put the `label` attribute in `<paper-listbox>` while it should be in `<paper-dropdown-menu>`.

> It appears to be impossible to select any value from the dropdown menu - you can click on them, but the list doesn't close, and the selected option name doesn't show up in the menu's text display.

The name not showing up should be the same as the previous point. I tried your example locally and the list actually doesn't close because of an error with the animations. This happens because the dropdown uses some Web Animations API features that have to be polyfilled:

```
$ npm install web-animations-js
```

```
<script src="node_modules/web-animations-js/web-animations-next-lite.min.js"></script>
```

Also, you're passing a string to `@selected-changed` (à la Polymer) while you should use interpolation:

```
@selected-change=${e => this. _homepageChanged(e)}

or

@selected-change=${this. _homepageChanged.bind(this)}
```

This way everything seems to work correctly:

[image: example]

Comment: To your first point, the first line of the render method is `const state = this.state;`, so that's not an issue.  You're right about the label, moving it to the parent element fixed the problem.  We've got the `web-animations` loaded - it gets packaged into our `base` package that's consumed by everything else.  Still, there may be an issue with the way it's being loaded on this page, so I'll double-check that.  You're dead right about the event handler - that was a legacy of converting this element from a Polymer 3 element, but I've fixed it now.

Comment: Follow-up: The selection problem doesn't seem to be related to the `web-animations-js` package - even when I insert a script tag referencing it into the element, or even to the layout that contains it, there's still no change in its behavior.  There are no console errors or any indication it believes it's misbehaving.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you importing `web-animations-next-lite.min.js` or `web-animations.min.js`?

Comment: The next-lite version

Comment: Ok, and are you importing the `html` template tag from `@polymer/polymer` or `lit-html`? Also, by "it gets packaged into our base package" you mean you're using a module bundler? It may be some kind of build issue or dependency version inconsistency...

Comment: The html tag is the one from lit-html. As for the dropdown, I don't think that's the case, as the same base package (yes, it's a module bundler) gets included on every page, and this same control is working just fine on those pages - the only difference I can identify is that those other elements are extended from PolymerElement rather than lit-element.

Comment: Well, I finally figured out the problem... I wasn't importing `paper-listbox` -_-  Sorry you spent so long trying to help me with the dumbest problem ever!

Comment: Don't worry, I hope I was helpful :)

Comment: I tried paper-dropdown-menu recently with lit-element and could not get the data from the selection using the above. In the end I used @selected-changed="${(e) => {this.changedHandler(e)}}"> on the paper-listbox element and using e.detail.value in the handler. See this post also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56056122/eventlistener-for-paper-dropdown-menu-in-lit-html